# How to simplify this integral-included expression?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper, but I get stuck in one step.  Consider the following expression 
$$\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)\{(r_1+r_2-1)+(1-\lvert r_1-r_2 \rvert) \exp [\lvert r_1-r_2 \rvert -(r_1+r_2)]\} \tag{1}$$
By considering $r=\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert$ we get
$$\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 r_1 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)+\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2^2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)+\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)-\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)\exp [r -(r_1+r_2)]+\frac {1}{r_1}\int_0^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)\exp [r -(r_1+r_2)] \tag{2} $$ 
The final result has the following form, but I don't understand how they have broken the limits of integral and reached the following experssion 
$$\int_0^{\infty}dr r \exp (-4\beta r^2+r)+\int_{r_1}^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)\exp(-2r_1)-\int_0^{r_1}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2-r_2)+\frac {1}{r_1}\{ \int_0^{\infty}dr r^2 \exp (-4\beta r^2+r)-\int_0^{\infty}dr r \exp (-4\beta r^2+r)+ \int_0^{r_1}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2-r_2)+ \int_0^{r_1}dr_2 r_2^2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2-r_2)+[\int_{r_1}^{\infty}dr_2 r_2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)-\int_{r_1}^{\infty}dr_2 r_2^2 \exp (-4\beta r_2^2+r_2)]\exp (-2r_1)\} \tag{3}$$
Can anyone help me to find a way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cut down on the indice tracking by replacing $a = r_1, r = r_2$. Also, for notational convenience, let $g(r) = re^{-4\beta r^2 + r}$. Your original expression becomes

$$\frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)\{(a+r-1)+(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r}\}\\=\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r) + \frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)r-\frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r) + \frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r}$$

Now assuming $a > 0$, you can break $$\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r} \\= \int_0^adr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r} + \int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r}$$

When $r < a, |a - r| - a - r = -2r$ and so,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^adr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r} &= \int_0^adr\, g(r)(1+r-a)e^{-2r}\\&=\int_0^adr\, g(r)e^{-2r} + \int_0^adr\, g(r)r e^{-2r}-a\int_0^adr\, g(r)e^{-2r}\end{align}$$

When $r > a, |a - r| - a - r = -2a$, and so
$$\begin{align}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r} &= e^{-2a}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)(1 -r + a)\\&=  e^{-2a}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r) -  e^{-2a}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)r + a e^{-2a}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)\end{align}$$

Putting it all together, 
$$\frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)\{(a+r-1)+(1- |a - r|)e^{|a - r| - a - r}\}=\\\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r) + \frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)r-\frac 1a\int_0^{\infty}dr\, g(r)\\+\frac1a\int_0^adr\, g(r)e^{-2r} + \frac1a\int_0^adr\, g(r)r e^{-2r}-\int_0^adr\, g(r)e^{-2r}\\+\frac{e^{-2a}}a\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r) -  \frac{e^{-2a}}a\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)r + e^{-2a}\int_a^{\infty}dr\, g(r)$$

Your expression is just this one substituting the original expressions, and doing some grouping.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and your time.